# Redirect oldDomain.com/folder/page/ to newDomain.com/page/

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have WordPress installed in a folder and have gone through [this process](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) in the WordPress codex to remove the sub-folder from the url. Works beautifully, oldDomain.com/folder/page/ is now oldDomain.com/page/.

My client wants to change the domain name for the site. Everything is redirecting except this case if people have the old url bookmarked - oldDomain.com/folder/page/ to newDomain.com/page/.

I tried this and nothing seems to happen:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldDomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.newDomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Similarly nothing happens when trying this:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works for the url but seems to break something with the stylesheets etc as all formatting disappears

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/(.*)$ /$1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.newDomain.com/$1
```

Try this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply! Unfortunately nothing appears to happen. I am getting a 404 error. I even tried
`Redirect 301 ^oldDomain.com/folder/(.*)$ http://www.newDomain.com/$1`